# nested collapsible container in drawio?

Tags: diagram, draw.io

I'm wondering if it's possible to nest collapsible containers? In the picture below I have a container containing various lists of text organised in "sections"; it'd be great to be able to collapse the sections individually as well.

[image]

Related query, since I'm creating those boxes programmatically – is it possible to create the text content programmatically and not need to position them with absolute y positions? With the user interface I can just add a new text box and it automatically stacks below the current one, and the container expands. If I create those with a script it seems I need to provide the y positions and sizes myself.

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding a new container for every section (as shown in the attachment) and check if it suits your needs. I created a simple test diagram, it could be improved visually.

nested containers

[image]

Comment: thanks! I didn't see the attachment though, did you link to a file somewhere, or could you post the XML chunk here? My attempt wasn't very successful and it didn't look like the parent container resizes when children are expanded.